# Spring-agent: Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing

Tags: java, ubuntu, docker

I am trying to run application using Docker. Application is Java program running on Tomcat. So, I am building an image and my `Dockerfile` looks like:

```
FROM tomcat:7.0.72-jre8

COPY Tomcat/ $CATALINA_HOME/

ENV JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -javaagent:$CATALINE_HOME/lib/spring-agent-2.5.6.jar -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -Dorg.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK=true"
```

As you see, I am using `-javaagent` option, but it causes:

```
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /lib/spring-agent-2.5.6.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
```

I've tried the same through setting `JAVA_OPTS` in `setenv.sh` - the same exception. I am sure that the lib is copied to container and It exists on specified path. I checked it by running same image without `javaagent`option and then access it in terminal. `spring-agent` was in lib folder, so I am a little bit stuck.

I am new Ubuntu user and I guess there are could be any permission problems etc.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The right way would be to let Docker build the jar file instead passing a previous created jar file. I did it like this: https://github.com/glapp/mape/blob/master/Dockerfile

This might be helpful for your Spring app: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/

Comment: how could this be helpful with javaagent problem? Really, like thing to mention, but I don't think it is the solution.

Comment: Why do you think that javaagent is the problem? The error message states that it has problem with opening the zip file or that the manifest file is missing. Did you already made sure that the manifest file is in your jar file? I suspect this is the real cause.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem was in `$CATALINA_HOME` as that variable had been missed when `javaagent` option was invoked, so I found temporary solution to specify the path like `/usr/local/tomcat/` instead of `$CATALINA_HOME`.

Quite unexpected, as on the step before I am copying files to `$CATALINA_HOME` and it works.

I would still not check this answer as correct because it doesn't look like good solution. Any ideas still appreciated.